# Can you use Google Analytics to figure out which pages got clicks from search engines? (The landing pages report is polluted with other data)

Tags: google-analytics, google-search, traffic, landing-page

Related to this question [How can pages which aren't indexed be reported as landing pages in Google Analytics?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74477/how-can-pages-which-arent-indexed-be-reported-as-landing-pages-in-google-analyt)

I need to be able to find out which pages are being found in the SERPs using Google Analytics. But as Landing pages reports seem to include traffic to no-indexed pages (so they can never have been the 'real' landing page found in Google), is there any way I can get a report on which pages were the initial ones that were returned for a search term in the SERPS?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

1) Behavior -> Site Content -> Landing Page

2) Choose Keyword as you Secondary Dimension

3) Click on Advanced Filter

4) Select Include -> Landing Page -> Contains -> [enter your landing page url]

This should pull up the landing page with all of the keywords if there are any. You might not see them all since a lot of keywords now a days come as 'not provided'

Note: this will also pull all keywords from your campaign tracking code and etc.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and checked many URLs,but still many which aren't indexed. Either they have been deindexed, or this report still includes landing pages which weren't the initial ones that were returned for a search term in the SERPS.

Answer (score 0):

If you link your Google Analytics and Google Webmaster Tools accounts you can get a more accurate landing page report that is available under "Acquisition" → "Search Engine Optimization" → "Landing Pages".

The data there is from Google's servers rather than based on data collected from your users via the JavaScript snippet.  In addition to seeing which pages on your site are popular landing pages from Google, you can also see which ones appear in the search engine results even when the users don't click: the report gives you impression data.

Comment: Thanks, although ideally I need to be able to tie it up with the extra data you get in the GA reports, such as CR, Revenue, etc.